# Search through emails and open up unsubscribe links

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a project from Automate the Boring Stuff and I am supposed to write a program that scans through my email and finds the unsubscribe links and opens them in a browser.

This is the code I have right now, but I am not sure why it won't open any of the emails in a new browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#! Python3
# Write a program that scans through your email account,finds all the
# unsubscribe links in all your emails, and automatically opens them in a browser.

import imapclient
import pyzmail
import webbrowser
import bs4

# User input
user_email = input('Enter your email: ')
user_pass = input('Enter your password: ')

# Connects to IMAP Server
imap_obj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
imap_obj.login(user_email, user_pass)
imap_obj.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)
UIDs = imap_obj.gmail_search('after:2018/07/13 before:2018/07/14 unsubscribe')
raw_messages = imap_obj.fetch(UIDs, ['BODY[]'])

for i in UIDs:
    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(raw_messages[i][b'BODY[]'])
    raw_soup = message.html_part.get_payload().decode(message.html_part.charset)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw_soup, 'html.parser')
    for unsub in soup.findAll('a'):
        print(unsub)
        break
        if 'Unsubscribe' in unsub:
            webbrowser.open(unsub)

imap_obj.logout()
```

Comment: Did you check if the URLs that you are finding in the code are valid?

Comment: Sorry, I am still a beginner but how can I check if they are valid?

Comment: You can just print them and copy+paste it in the browser.

Comment: Ok, i edited my code and it returns all the 'a' in the HTML, but I still cannot get it to open the unsubscribe link.

Comment: I can't comment yet, but wpercy's solution works if you replace `unsub.href` with `unsub.get('href')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if 'Unsubscribe' is in the text of the element. `in` won't work as you expect on things that aren't iterable (like a bs4 element tag). Something like

```
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw_soup, 'html.parser')
    for unsub in soup.find_all('a'):
        print((unsub.text, unsub.get('href')))
        if 'unsubscribe' in unsub.text.lower():
            webbrowser.open(unsub.get('href'))
```

(note the `unsub.href` in the last line, you need to be accessing the attributes of these tags, not the reference to the tag itself)

Comment: Seems like there is a <span> tag that includes the word "Unsubscribe" inside the a href element. Any tips on how to make this work?

Comment: It should still work, when you call `unsub.text`, it'll parse out all of the text enclosed in the tag, including if that text is included in another tag. It's possible that it wasn't capitalized, which I've added a fix for

Comment: It still doesn't work. It just returns the values (' ', None) or ('Unsubcribe', None'). Not really sure how to solve this. Im struggling on this last part of the code.

Comment: it's impossible to tell what's happening without seeing your actual input, actual output and desired output. please update your question